# Training model for AirPassengers dataset

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, djl

In the DJL example, the AirPassengers is used to predict, but the code to train the model is not shown as it uses an already trained model.

After some Googling, I found a Python solution for training that model: https://ts.gluon.ai/v0.11.x/index.html#simple-example, which is super simple code.

DJL shows an example of how to train a time series model, but it seems so complicated, and I could not translate it to train the air passengers example. Any hint on how to do it?

Thank you very much.